# How to build UIMap for a complete page, rather than record certain actions?

Tags: testing, user-interface, coded-ui-tests

I am doing some Coded UI test.
I want to generate a UIMap class for the page under test.

Is there any efficient way or tool to do this? I don't want to click all the controls on the page one by one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a good idea, but probably isn't.  Any given 'page' or grouping of controls... could really be tens or potentially even hundreds of UI elements.  The actual controls that the user could interact with might be very small.

You wouldn't want every label and every border etc mucking up the available options.  So while it's a pain to click on each control in order for it to show in the map, it's probably best to keep your tests concise and robust.

Also, if there are a whole bunch of controls the user actually interacts with on one 'page,' I would even suggest creating separate UIMaps for sections of the 'page.'

Comment: I like the idea of UI sections for a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea at all.  You will want your CUITs broken up as much as possible.  If you put every control in one UIMap the map can become way too large causing added time to debug the simplest things.

The other reason to break up your CUITs into separate UIMaps is because if something happens to one of the controls in the UIMap (say you accidently deleted it) and you cannot fix it, you will need to start over from scratch!  Much easier to redo a couple of controls rather than the entire page.